# Читать все txt файлы из папки

Tags: c#

Есть папка, в ней 5 txt файлов, задача софта чтобы он искал строку во всех файлах(пусть показывает файл и строку, которую нашел), пока что у меня получилось только что он читает только 1-й файл, остальные, почему-то нет...как это сделать через File.ReadLines? С начало надо получить все файлы txt из директории потом читать все в поисках строки..

```
foreach (string lines in Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Users\Grand\Desktop\folder1\", "*.txt"))//получили все тхт'шники..
            {
string filename = File.ReadLines(lines);
```

а дальше как readlines юзать ?
Что то не хочет пахать..

Comment: Есть подозрение что вы путаете имена переменных. В lines скорее всего должно быть имя файла, а в filename - прочитанные строки...

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов может быть..

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов но почему он ищет только в 1-м файле, а не во всех ?

Comment: @Quarsh781, почему ты думаешь, что он ищет только в одном файле?

Comment: @Grundy потому-что я открыл остальные файлы, и вижу там строку, которую мне надо, а софт почему-то не видит ее!

Comment: @Quarsh781, как ты проверяешь, что не видит?

Comment: @Grundy и что ты хочешь в ответ ?

Comment: @Quarsh781, очевидно, то, как именно ты проверяешь: смотришь в отладчике? смотришь конечный вывод? смотришь логи?

Answer (score 2):

Пускай существует некий "условный" каталог с **.txt* файлами, которые не пустые.

```
string storagePath = "/path/to/file";
var fileStorage = new List<string[]>();
try{        
    var filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(storagePath, "*.txt")); //string[]
    foreach(string path in filePaths){
        string[] fileLines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(path);
        fileStorage.Add(fileLines);
    }
    foreach(string[] fileLines in fileStorage){
        foreach(fileLine in fileLines){
            Console.WriteLine(fileLine);
        }
    Console.WriteLine();
    }
} catch (Exception e){
    /* todo */
}
```

Дальше, если Вы хотите делать (если я правильно понял вопрос), то Вы можете его разбить на более мелкие составляющие - слова:

```
var matchWord = "some_word";
var delimiters = new Char[]{'.', ' ', ';'} //массив разделителей
int i = 1;
foreach(string[] fileLines in fileStorage){
   Console.WriteLine("Search in file #" + i++);       
   foreach(fileLine in fileLines){
       var words = fileLine.Split(delimiters);
       foreach(word in words){
           if(word.Equals(someWord){
               return word . " finded!";
           }
       }
   }
}
```

Да спагетти-код в примере ужасный, но... Вы знаете куда двигаться)

Comment: `try` блок лучше бы делать полегче, допустим это: `string storagePath = "/path/to/file"; ` и `var fileStorage = new List<string[]>();` можно было сделать и до захода в блок.

Comment: @Bulson Вы правы, можно сделать и так, но почему?) (просто интересно)

Comment: Ну, это во многих руководствах говорится о том, что в `try` нужно размещать только тот код, который непосредственно может вызвать исключение, остальное должно быть во вне этого блока. Да, и с точки зрения читабельности кода легче воспринимаются короткие блоки с меньшей вложенностью. Если можете [читать](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1308432) на инглише.

Comment: ```пусть показывает файл и строку, которую нашел``` - вы теряете информацию о файле. Да и так ли необходимо в данном случае считывать все файлы в папке в память?

Answer (score 1):

Вам по сути надо:

1. Найти файлы в папке
2. Считать каждый файл построчно
3. Если строка из файла содержит нужный текст - вывести файл и строку

Простейшая реализация

```
void FindMatches(string directory, string text)
{
    foreach (var file in Directory.GetFiles(directory, "*.*"))
    {
        foreach (var line in File.ReadLines(file))
        {
            if (line.Contains(text))
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Found match {file} - {line}");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Сценарий использования:

```
FindMatches(@"My Directory", "My Text");
```